# Problem with jQuery.slideUp

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a problem with Jquery, it works but it seems to flicker once complete:

Exmaple here:

http://www.zombiewrath.com/maintest.php

Why does it do that?

Here is the code:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="button" onclick="test()">

<div id="tablemin">
<table bordercolor="#0000FF" width="670" border="1">
        <tr>
          <td class="style5" width="400" valign="top" style="width: 300px"><b><u>Personal Feed: </u></b><br>
          </td>
          <td class="style5" width="355" valign="top"><u><strong>Live Feed:</strong> </u><br>
              <div id="ReloadTime3" style="width: 350px">  
</div></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="style5" valign="top" colspan="3" style="width: 488px"><b><u>Local news for Zone B-4...</u></b></td></tr>
      </table>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document.body).click(function () {
    $('#tablemin').slideUp('slow');
});  
</script>
</body></html>
```

*Note, i'm using IE 7, if it doesn't flicker at the end of the slide for you, please say :) -And post which browser...

Why would it flicker in IE 7 =/

Thanks.

Comment: It's not flickering for me here on FF 3.6.x

Comment: Just a note, it looks fine in firefox and chrome, but does flicker in IE 8.

Comment: Try settings a width/height for #tablemin .. no flicker in chrome

Comment: Doesn't flicker on Chrome on mac. I would guess this is only IE -- I would suggest trying styles like "position: relative" and "zoom: 1" on the element you're animating and possibly its parent.

Comment: Works currently in IE 7 :) (Using animate to 1px then a super quick fade) -Can someone using FF and chrome confirm it doesn't flicker?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interesting, had the same problem very recently. This also happens in IE6, every other browser deals with it properly.

This is not a real solution but possibly you could use animate instead?

```
$('#tablemin').animate({height: '0px'},1000);
```

Make sure you have overflow: hidden on tablemin.

Comment: Although setting height to 1px works. :) However that 1px looks annoying :P

Comment: ^Fixed that with a fade added to end :)

Comment: @Steven Tilling - Ah yeah sorry, thats what I had to do too, set it to 1px then hide it. Glad you got it :D

Comment: This helped me a lot with a slideUp issue - many thanks @cadaa.

Answer (score 1):

It flickers because of the javascript error caused by this line

```
<input type="button" onclick="test()">
```

I don't see a test() function

Comment: which that portion of the code isn't shown in your snippet you posted but it is on your site

Comment: Editted with new code, my bad... (Removing button now btw) -Lets hope for a difference...

Comment: still flickers without the js error... This must be the problem then.  http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/5062 which someone reported ie8 in ie7 mode and ie7 flicker and they marked with wontfix

Comment: Works currently in IE 7 :) (Using animate to 1px then a super quick fade) -Can someone using FF and chrome confirm it doesn't flicker?